# How do I remove entire div with button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pug

Can someone help me to write a method, that lets me remove entire b-card after clicking the icon with @click ?

````
           b-card  
              b-col.message.d-flex.justify-content-between.p-0(lg="12")
                b-col.d-flex.align-items-center(lg="11")
                  b-icon.mr-2.msg(icon="exclamation-circle" variant="success")
                  p.font-weight-bold.m-0.mr-2 Message
                  p.mb-0.msginfo - Update your measurements.  
                b-col.d-flex.align-items-center(lg="1")
                  p.mb-0.msginfo.font-weight-bold 11:20 
                  b-icon.ml-2(icon="x-circle" variant="danger" @click="removeNotification")
    ```
````

Comment: can you introduce new property to toggle the visibility of the b-card, then on the method you can set the visibility property to false. You could do this by surrounding the b-card by a v-if

Comment: I did it like this, but I have couple of them and it removes all of them instead of the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new variable like `showCard` initially set to true and in
`removeNotification() { this.showCard = false }`
and in your template `b-card(v-show="showCard")`. This will remove the card when `showCard` is false.